# Deserialize Nested Dictionary in from Json C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a class something like this

```
public class A{
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
    public Guid businessId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, long> rights { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to covert this json to this class

```
    {
    "userId": "dc2af693-72e1-49a7-80aa-6416c6536bdf",
    "businessId": "0110eea4-7a47-4a7c-95ea-10547ab49652",
    "rights": "{\"19\":1,\"17\":15,\"18\":1,\"23\":1,\"1\":31,\"20\":3,\"3\":1,\"16\":0}",
   }
```

But when Im trying to convert it with NewtonSoft.Json

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

I get the following error **Cannot Cast System.string to System.Dictionary<int,long>**
What happens is that my rights get converted to a string something like this

```
"{"19":1, "17":15, "18":1, ..., "16":0}"
```

If I deserialize this string again it works as I desire is there better method to do this.

Comment: Actually the content of "rights" is a string, as all the quotes are escaped by backslashes (\")

Comment: Have you tried creating a sample object and serializing it first to see what it looks like serialized? I find this to be a good method of finding some of the more easy-to-miss errors when building complex strings.

Comment: The data in `rights` is effectively a Json representation of a dictionary, so this could be a two-step process: first deserialize `rights` as a string, them deserialize it again as a dictionary: `Dictionary<int, long> RightValues => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, long>>(rights);`

Comment: @CMGeek this json is the payload of a jwt token where all of are added as claims to user of the token.

Comment: You'll need to decorate the `rights` property with a custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) - in the custom `JsonConverter` you'll be able to deserialize the string and then convert into a dictionary.

Comment: Can you change the origin of the JSON so it does not turn integers into strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `rights` is in string format, you can add custom `JsonConverter` which converts the string to dictionary

```
public class A
{
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
    public Guid businessId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(RightsSerializer))]
    public Dictionary<int, long> rights { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the RightsSerializer

```
public class RightsSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<int, long>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;

        var jt = JToken.Load(reader);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, long>>(jt.Value<String>());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

And DeserializeObject

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

Comment: I'm doing like this currently but the class is scoped which I can inject anywhere to get the value isn't there any short-hand where my class is contains the dictionary.

Comment: @MuhammadJamali, then you need custom runtime serializer. updated the post to reflect the same

Answer (score 0):

changing the class to something like this will help. althoutgh you need to make code better than this.

```
        public class A
    {
        public Guid userId { get; set; }
        public Guid businessId { get; set; }

        //[JsonConverter(typeof(Dictionary<int, long>))]
        public string rights { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<int, long> rightss => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, long>>(rights);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without deserializing twice, but you could hide it with a private subclass.

```
public class A {
   public Guid userId {get;set;}
   public Guid businessId {get;set;}
   public Dictionary<int, long> rights {get;set;}

   private class B {
      public Guid userId {get;set;}
      public Guid businessId {get;set;}
      public string rights {get;set;}
   }

   private B b;

   public A (string json) {
      var o = new JsonSerializerOptions();
      o.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
      b = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<B>(json, o);
      userId = b.userId;
      businessId = b.businessId;
      rights = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, long>>(b.rights,o);
   }
}
```

Usage with test in fiddle:

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Su1uF9)